Issue with Laravel Passport's createToken method not functioning
Error: Unauthorize Grant type
use Laravel\Passport\Client as OClient; 

 $oClient = OClient::where('password_client', 1)->first();
                         $client_id = $oClient->id;
                         $client_secret = $oClient->secret;
                          
                            $request->request->add([
                                'username' => $email,
                                'password' => $password,
                                'grant_type' => 'password',
                                'client_id' => $client_id,
                                'client_secret' => $client_secret,
                                'scope' => ''
                            ]);

                            $tokenRequest = Request::create(
                                env('APP_URL').'/oauth/token',
                                'post'
                            );
                            
                            $response = Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);

I have run command php artisan passport:client --password`
but still not working
